# Put a JPanel on top of JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jlabel

I have put a background image on the JFrame using `setIcon` for label.
Also I have put `Button`s on the `JFrame`, I want a `JScrollPane` ,which can show Image.
Without showing background image, I am able to see the `JScrollPane` but with it I cannot see the `JScrollPane`.

Comment: Show some Code, what have you tried so far. Give a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can check.

Comment: give a screenshot too

Comment: @Patrick +1.  One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556).

Comment: Actually I'm doing my project in NetBeans.

Comment: So I just dragged a scrollPane and added the label to it.